# Настройка Xdebug с использованием локального сервера от PHP.

Tags: php, xdebug

Здравствуйте, перерыл много источников и мануалов, но не нашел настройки xdebug, когда мы сервер запускаем, к примеру, через

```
php -S localhost:8888
```

Я настроил в php.ini

```
zend_extension = C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=«localhost»
xdebug.remote_port=8888
xdebug.remote_handler=«dbgp»
```

phpinfo() показывает, что xdebug настроен и готов к использованию. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

настроил сервер через PhpStorm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включаю прослушивание, ставлю красную точку на нужном моменте и включаю дебагер через сервер[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но выдает вот это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через этот же порт запущено веб приложение на локальном сервере.

как избавить и получить нормальный дебаг?

Comment: К чему такие извращения? Это же не полноценный веб сервер

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan ну я бы хотел дебажить на своем локальном сервере.

Comment: Есть же множество вариантов: xammp, iis, openserver на крайний случай если речь про windows идёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю простой способ настройки:

1. Создаем сервер в настройках phpstorm
2. В настройке Run/Debug Configuration создаем новую конфигурацию PHP Remote Debug
3. Указываем в ней название нашего сервера и ide key(session id)=PHPSTORM
4. Скачиваем дополнение для вашего браузера "Xdebug helper"
5. После установки, кликаем правым кликом на его иконку, заходим в настройки и прописываем IDE key=PHPSTORM , сохраняем
6. В phpstorm находим иконку жучка, с ее помощью можно включить дебаггер
7. Открываем нужную вам локальную веб страницу. Кликаем левым кликом на иконку Xdebug helper и включаем его, нажатием на кнопку DEBUG

Надеюсь, это было полезным для Вас